# Default remote for Git push

Tags: git, git-push

In [Git-config](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) you can see:

> branch.name.remote
>
> When on branch <name>, it tells git fetch and git push which remote to
>   fetch from/push to. The remote to push to may be overridden with
>   remote.pushDefault (for all branches). The remote to push to, for the
>   current branch, may be further overridden by branch.<name>.pushRemote.
>   If no remote is configured, or if you are not on any branch, it
>   defaults to origin for fetching and ***remote.pushDefault*** for ***pushing***.

Now I have a `cloned` repository and a branch which is named **`test`** and is **checkouted**. Here you can see contents of `config` file of the cloned repository:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = ...
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

As you see, `branch.`**`test`**`.pushRemote`, `remote.pushDefault` and `branch.`**`test`**`.remote` are not set there. So I expect when I do

```
$ git push
```

I will get

```
fatal: No configured push destination.
```

But I get

```
Everything up-to-date
```

It seems `Git` uses `origin` instead of not configured `remote.pushDefault`. But why when docs say

> it defaults to ***remote.pushDefault*** for ***pushing***.

Edit:

In [Git-push](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html) you can see:

> When the command line does not specify where to push with the
>   <repository> argument, branch.*.remote configuration for the current
>   branch is consulted to determine where to push. If the configuration
>   is missing, it defaults to ***origin***.

It think there is a conflict between using `origin` and `remote.pushDefault`.

Comment: The "test" branch's default push location is not overriden by any configuration items so it defaults to `origin` which does appear to be configured.  (I assume that "..." indicates an actual value that you have left out.) So I do not understand your confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git's push code (and pull too, really) is (in my opinion) unnecessarily complicated because it tries to retain a large number of historical behaviors, several of which were bad ideas.

Let's look first at [the REMOTES section of the `git-push` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html#_remotes_a_id_remotes_a):

> The name of one of the following can be used instead of a URL as *repository* argument:
>
> - a remote in the Git configuration file: `$GIT_DIR/config`,
> - a file in the `$GIT_DIR/remotes` directory, or
> - a file in the `$GIT_DIR/branches` directory.
>
> All of these also allow you to omit the refspec from the command line because they each contain a refspec which git will use by default.

(The name of a remote is—again, this is just my opinion—the only one of these that really should survive today.  I think the specified-URL method probably should be moved to a plumbing command, and `git push` could return to being a simple script, although the Git-on-Windows folks are, alas, trying to convert *away* from scripts due to Windows performance issues.)

Fortunately, you are using the named-remote method, so we can ignore most of this.  Specifically, the refspec is optional because you are using a remote in `$GIT_DIR/config`.

Next, we should clearly distinguish between syntax (nouns and verbs and such that you enter on a command line) and semantics (behavior).  Once we toss out the extra varieties of "remote" we're left with two tasks:

1. Select a remote.
2. Select a refspec.

The *syntax* you used was `git push`, i.e., no specified *`repository`* argument and no specified *`refspec`*.  So for step 1, selecting a remote, Git uses the paragraph you quoted in your edit: find the current branch—in this case, `test`–and then look up `branch.test.remote`.  This is not configured (is "missing"), so Git falls back to using `origin`.

(There's a bug in the quoted documentation paragraph, as it fails to mention `branch.branch.pushRemote`, which in this case would be `branch.test.pushRemote`.  The correct sequence is (1) look for the branch-specific pushRemote; (2) look for the branch-specific remote; (3) look for `remote.pushDefault` if Git version 1.8.3 or newer; (4) try the word `origin`.  This documentation bug is still in git 2.8.1.)

Since `origin` *is* a valid remote name, step 1 succeeds and we move on to step 2, selecting a refspec.  This part does not have you puzzled, but just for completeness:

> When the command line does not specify what to push with *`refspec ...`*
>    arguments or `--all`, `--mirror`, `--tags` options, the command finds the
>    default *`refspec`* by consulting `remote.*.push` configuration, and if it
>    is not found, honors `push.default` configuration to decide what to push
>    (See [`git-config(1)`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) for the meaning of `push.default`).

So in this case, Git looks for `remote.origin.push` and, since that is not set, `push.default`.  If `push.default` is not set, there is a "default default", which in Git prior to 2.0 was `matching` and is now (Git 2.0 or newer) `simple`.  This default `push.default` means that there is *always* a refspec.

The default remote-name `origin` means that there is *usually* a remote.  This fails only when there is no `[remote "origin"]` section in your `$GIT_DIR/config`.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the explenation for `remote.pushDefault`:

> remote.pushDefault
>             The remote to push to by default. Overrides branch.
>             .remote for all branches, and is overridden by branch.
>             .pushRemote for specific branches.

So it's meant for *overriding* the default remote when pushing. When it's not set, it does nothing, and the default remote of origin comes into play.

Note that `remote.pushDefault` has been added later (v1.8.3), so it would break a lot of things when these semantics would change.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is not as simple as for fetching, because there is a list of fallbacks which need to be considered:

- [`branch.<name>.pushRemote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-branchltnamegtpushRemote)
- [`remote.pushDefault`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-remotepushDefault)
- [`branch.<name>.remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-branchltnamegtremote)
- `origin`

To get the remote programatically, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52913659/5353461).