# Programmatically get remote used for git push

Tags: git, push, git-push, git-remote

How can I obtain the remote used when issuing `git push`?

I want to be able to use this in a script, or in git alises.

Related: [Default remote for git fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16838158/5353461)

Answer (score 3):

The answer is not as simple as for fetching, because there is a list of fallbacks which need to be considered:

- [`branch.<name>.pushRemote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-branchltnamegtpushRemote)
- [`remote.pushDefault`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-remotepushDefault)
- [`branch.<name>.remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-branchltnamegtremote)
- `origin`

These aliases take into account all of the above:

```
branch-name = "symbolic-ref --short HEAD"  # https://stackoverflow.com/a/19585361/5353461
branch-remote-fetch = !"branch=$(git branch-name \"$1\") && git config branch.\"$branch\".remote || echo origin #"
branch-remote-push  = !"branch=$(git branch-name \"$1\") && git config branch.\"$branch\".pushRemote || git config remote.pushDefault || git branch-remote-fetch #"
```

And, as a bonus, for the URL:

```
branch-url-push = !"remote=$(git branch-remote-push  \"$1\") && git remote get-url --push \"$remote\" #"  # cognizant of pushInsteadOf
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on whether you want the remote's name or its URL, also

```
git push --dry-run --porcelain --verbose
```

and looking at the URL after "To " in the first line might do.

Comment: `Enter passphrase for /home/ravi/.ssh/XXXX:`
`git-receive-pack: permission denied: XXXX`
`fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`

`Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.`

Comment: Or: `fatal: No configured push destination.` `Either specify the URL from the command-line or configure a remote repository using...`

Comment: Well, of course `--dry-run` only works if a real push would work. If you want to be able to get the remote a push would use even if a real push would fail you should probably make that more clear in your question.

Comment: In any case, if you add `--verbose`, the URL is still printed.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
$ git remote get-url --push origin
```

From the docs [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote):

```
**get-url**

Retrieves the URLs for a remote. Configurations for insteadOf and pushInsteadOf are expanded here. By default, only the first URL is listed.

With --push, push URLs are queried rather than fetch URLs.

With --all, all URLs for the remote will be listed.
```